# getting error in zend framework

Tags: php, html, zend-framework

print data after inner join of two tables in table format 
I am getting following error in below code:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in
>   /home/bina/public_html/studentzend/application/views/scripts/index/index.phtml
>   on line 57

Here is my code:

```
<?php if (count($this->messages)) : ?>
<ul id="messages">
<?php foreach ($this->messages as $message) : ?>
<li><?php echo $this->escape($message); ?></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>   </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
<div class="row">
<div class="span12">
    <a class="btn btn-primary" role="button" href="<?php echo $this->url(array('controller' => 'Index', 'action' => 'create')); ?>">Create Student</a>
    <h3>Recent Students</h3>

    <table class="table table-condensed">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>FirstName</th>
                <th>LastName</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Actions</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <body>
            <?php
            if(empty($this->students))
            {
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td><center>NO records found</center></td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }
            else  
            {
                //print_r($this->students);exit;
                $students=$this->students;
                $length=  sizeof($this->students);

                //echo $length;exit;

             for($i=0;$i<$length;$i++){ ?>
                <tr>
                <td><?php  echo $students[$i]['id']; ?> </td>
                <td><?php  echo $students[$i]['firstname']; ?> </td>
                 <td><?php  echo $students[$i]['lastname']; ?> </td>
                 <td><?php echo $students[$i]['email'];  ?></td>
                <td>
                        <a href="<?php  echo $this->url(array('controller' => 'index', 'action' => 'update', 'id' => $students->getId())); ?>">Edit</a> |
                        <a href="<?php  echo $this->url(array('controller' => 'index', 'action' => 'delete', 'id' => $students->getId())); ?>">Delete</a></td>
                </tr>


          <?php  } ?>

        </body>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are just missing a closing brace **`}`** for your `else` statement.

```
             <a href="<?php  echo $this->url(array('controller' => 'index', 'action' => 'delete', 'id' => $students->getId())); ?>">Delete</a></td>
            </tr>


        <?php  }} ?>
              //^-------- Add one there
```